# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (SQLite3::BusyException: database is locked

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, rubygems

I know this a duplicate question but i tried all other solutions did not work for me.
when I create new message it does not insert it in on first click and on the second click it insert the same message twice, if I look at the terminal after the first click i get

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (SQLite3::BusyException: database is locked: INSERT INTO "notifications" ("content", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)):
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (SQLite3::BusyException: database is locked: commit transaction):
```

solutions I tried are

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("BEGIN TRANSACTION; END;")
```

I got unknown file attribute: B.

```
bundle exec rake db:reset
```

it cleared all my data but I still got the same results.

```
default: &default
adapter: sqlite3
pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
timeout: 10000
```

I tried to increase timeout but it did not work for me.

app/controllers/messages_controller.rb

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
     before_action :authenticate_user!
     before_action :set_conversation

def index
    if current_user == @conversation.sender || current_user == @conversation.recipient
    @other = current_user == @conversation.sender ? @conversation.recipient : @conversation.sender
    @messages = @conversation.messages.order("created_at DESC")
    else
  redirect_to conversations_path, alert: "You don't have permission to view this."
    end
end
def create
   @message = @conversation.messages.new(message_params)
   @messages = @conversation.messages.order("created_at DESC")

if @message.save
   ActionCable.server.broadcast "conversation_#{@conversation.id}", message: render_message(@message)
   redirect_to conversation_messages_path(@conversation)
  end
end
private
  def render_message(message)
  self.render(partial: 'messages/message', locals: {message: message})
end
def set_conversation
  @conversation = Conversation.find(params[:conversation_id])
end
def message_params
  params.require(:message).permit(:context, :user_id)
 end
end
```

[This is an image from the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qi9mQ.png)

Comment: Im thinking of dropping the message  table and re creating but i feel is kinda risky to do that

Comment: I think you should offload to a background job. Have you looked at sidekiq?